# The name 'toW' does not exist in the current context issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need somehow pass  `double fromH, double toH, UIElement control` to the `AnimateH` method within of `sb.Completed` but I got the error

**The name 'toW' does not exist in the current context issue**

and etc..

How do i can fix it?

Thank you!

```
 void AnimateTop(double from, double to, double fromH, double toH, UIElement control)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("EFM - AnimateTop - from: " + from.ToString() + " to: " + to.ToString());
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            da.From = from;
            da.To = to;
            da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            sb.Children.Add(da);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, control);
            sb.Completed += (w, r) => 
            { 
                AnimateH(fromW, toW, control); // Here is the error
                control.UpdateLayout(); 
            };
            sb.Begin();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `toW` but it's not declared anywhere
or passed as parameter

If it's a value that comes from another place, you should passed as a parameter. If it's a value created from some method there, you should declare the type and get its value

```
TypeOftoW toW = MethodThatReturntoWValues();
```

before using it.

Answer (score 1):

The method is accepting parameters named `to` and `toH`, but never a `toW`. Unless it's a global variable in your class, it's not being declared anywhere (and if it were global, you wouldn't be receiving the error).

You should also be seeing a similar error for `fromW`, as it doesn't exist in the current context either (also, unless it's global).

Answer (score 1):

Just a few notes:

1. You're using a variable called toW (which by the way is very poorly named in and of itself. If you're gonna use acronyms as var names, use all lower or all caps, in some scenarios). Anyway, toW doesn't exist. You're probably looking for toH.
2. You should always name your variables such that someone who doesn't know the code can read and understand them.
3. Though it is a legal name, I wouldn't use `from` as a variable name, since it is also a LINQ keyword.